# Can I use a provisioningProvider to a custom web template?

Tags: web-template, provisioning-providers

I have problems with the sequence of my logic. I  have featere1 where I have my custom webtemplate. Then I have feature2 where I have implemented my default.aspx page. Feature1 is activating feature2. In feature2 I have created a evenreceiver on activating the feature. In this event receiver I would like to add lists to webpartzones of my default.aspx.

The problem is now, that in runtime when I create a new site and select my custom webtemplate, then it execute my eventreceiver to FAST and gives me an error that my default.aspx is not existing in the page library. This is not the only problem because also my declared lists in my onet.xml declared in feature1 are also not available at this point. So the sequence is not OK.

I would like to implement the sequence inside a provisioningprovider, but I I have read it is only available for site definition. Is there some other solution to fix this sequence problem?